# Onclick show/hide a div -only css and without href. NO jquery

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-transitions

[image: img]

Initially visible box to user is blue box with text "hey there and hello". After user click on hello, grey box with text "how to" occupies the space of blue box and hello text changes to "close" text content added through css.

Now when I click on close, grey box again goes invisible and blue box appears again with text "hey there and hello". I've tried using focus but it's not helping.

Below follows the css that I'm trying to use. It would be great if I get some help. Focus isn't working. Only css has to be used.No anchor link or hrefs it's all about plain text.

```css
.blue-card {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px 0 rgba(27, 29, 31, 0.05);
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}



.grey-card {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 20px;
  max-height: 155px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  padding-right: 2em;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  transition: 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s;
  transform: scale(1.4) translateY(-100px);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4) translateY(-100px);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.4) translateY(-100px);
}

.grey-card {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.grey-card {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
}

.grey-card-text {
  display: none;
}

.blue-box-text:focus~.grey-box {
  display: block;
}

.grey-box-text:focus~.blue-box-text {
  display: block;
}

.grey-box-text:before {
  content: "Close";
  font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-main">
  <div class="blue-card">
    <p class="blue-box-description">hey there</p>
    <div class="gs-c">
      <span class="blue-box-text">hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grey-card">
    <h4 class="grey-box-text">How to?</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the markup?

Comment: Where is html part ?

Comment: @LokeshGupta posting

Comment: have you tried using the 'checkbox hack' ? or that is not allowed either

Comment: What @MihaiT says. Turn the gray box into a label for a checkbox, make the checkbox invisible and use `~`.

Comment: @LokeshGupta added html

Comment: @MihaiT checkbox is not for plain text I guess not sure but either way if that works without jquery

Comment: Like you see here the text of both the box is shown at the same time ..... which is wrong instead second grey box text should be shown only when I click hello and hello text now will be replaced by "Close" and also second card content "how to" will be visible .... when you click on close - again hello and hey there is visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trick way to achieve your goal using Check box hack

See the example bellow

```css
#myid {
  display: none;
}

#mylabel:after {
  content: 'Hello';
}

#myid:checked~#mylabel:after {
  content: 'Close';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="myid" type="checkbox">
  <label id="mylabel" for="myid"></label>
</div>
```

And if you want to use text **Hello** in html and **Close** in css you can use this :

```css
#myid {
  display: none;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
}

#mylabel {
  display: inline-block;
}

#myid:checked~#mylabel:after {
  content: 'Close';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

#myid:checked~#mylabel {
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <input id="myid" type="checkbox">
  <label id="mylabel" for="myid">Hello</label>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but here you are adding even hello using css, only close has to be added using css, which is helpful in a way. And the rest box text where it will go it shows only when we click hello..... I've made changes in above code check once please

Comment: Ya @koku19 please up +1 this great answer ,
aw zidlou +1 .

Comment: Thanks @bRIMOs :), ya lkhchine :p

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `flex`box trick to change the order of your boxes. This will enable you to use the adjacent sibling selector both ways, thereby a work-around for the absence of previous-sibling selector in CSS.

**Idea:**

Have a wrapper container set to `display:flex`. Have your target `div`s absolutely positioned relative to this wrapper parent. Use `tabindex` to force the `div` to gain focus. Change the order of each other when focused along with opacity and position to aid the `transition` effects.

**Example Snippet:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: sans-serif; }
.wrap { display: flex; position: relative; width: 260px; }
.blue, .gray {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px; height: 3em; 
  margin: 4px; padding: 8px;
  cursor: pointer; transition: all 0.5s;
}
.blue { 
  order: 1; left: 0; opacity: 1;
  background-color: #33d; 
}
.gray { 
  order: 2; left: 50%; opacity: 0;
  background-color: #bbb; 
}
.blue:focus + .gray { order: 1; left: 0; opacity: 1;}
.blue:focus { order: 2; left: 50%; opacity: 0; }

.gray:focus + .blue { order: 1; left: 0; opacity: 1; }
.gray:focus { order: 2; left: 50%; opacity: 0; }

.blue::after { content: 'Hello'; color: #fff; }
.gray::after { content: 'Close'; color: #333; }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="blue" tabindex="1"></div>
  <div class="gray" tabindex="2"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Gotchas:**

Once the focus changes from the default, and related properties are changed; then losing focus will reset the elements back to their defaults. This effectively means that you no longer necessarily need to click the gray `div` to reset. You can click anywhere on the document and the states will reset.

**Learning:**

Although this achieves what you want, i.e. no anchors, no inputs, no checkboxes, no JavaScript etc., this won't take you far, and serves no meaningful purpose other than to just show that it can be done somehow. Use the tools which are meant for the specific purpose.